# How to reduce or remove the need for filesystem checks

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, filesystems, hard-drive-cache

I am currently running windows 7 in a virtual machine. After several days of disk-intensive I/O, the virtual machine crashes and needs to run a filesystem check when booting the guest OS back up. (The Virtual machine crashes, not the host machine)

Is there any settings or software that I can use to prevent or shorten filesystem checks when the filesystem is not unmounted cleanly, even at the cost of performance?

I'm not currently looking to solve the VM crashing issue.

*** EDIT > MY TRY ***

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management
```

change the *LargeSystemCache* DWORD from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually want to *disable* disk caching. The filesystem checks occur because there was data in the disk cache that was not cleanly written to disk before the system died.

1. Right click on the harddrive in My Computer
2. Select the `Hardware` tab
3. Click `Properties`
4. Click `Change Settings`
5. Select the `Policies` tab
6. Uncheck "Enable write caching on the device"
7. Click `OK` until all windows are closed.

This will make sure that all data is immediately written to the harddisk, which should reduce the chances of incurring a filesystem check when you reboot the system.

Comment: It still may not prevent the filesystem checks altogether (it still has to check the filesystem any time it crashes to see if it's damaged or not), but doing this should make those checks significantly faster.

Answer (score 0):

It is not about performance.

After a crash the file system may be in an inconsistent state with potentially
corrupted files and directory structures.

Disabling file system check may result in incorrect operation of the virtual
machine and in such a situation it will be much more preferable to solve
the crash problem.

If you cannot solve the crash problem, try to periodically reboot the virtual
machine, which also may reduce probability of system crashes.